# Use View Email as Web Page with Personalization issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm trying to find the best solution for Use View Email as Web Page with Personalisation issue where let's assume customer receive a welcome an email then moves to another stage. Hence the customer doesn't exist in the first DE then customer never open his email the first day. 4 days later he opens and click on Use View Email as Web page, it will give him all the personalisation fields blanks since he is not part of the DE. Any best solution may be _messageContext with VAWP? Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain why is he not part of the DE after 4 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove someone from the DE that they were sent from then the 'View Online' will not work. I would consider revising your process to keep subscribers you've sent to in the DE such as have a date field or boolean field in the DE so you know if they've been sent to. Alternatively just remove the online version from your emails.

However if it's a Journey then you can just rely on the High Water Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, If we use the guided send and Automation send to send an email, once the data is deleted from sendable data extension, not be able to view the email as a web page personalization string values.
 Instead, try to use Journey Builder Send for all email sends.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314287&type=1